Does anyone have a citeable reference for Barbalats lemma applied to functions with derivatives approaching uniform continuity?
So I am almost positive that the proof of Barbalats lemma found in the link below can be trivially extended to also prove true for functions with derivates that only approach a uniformly continuous function, rather than having the derivative just be a uniformly continuous function like in the linked proof:
https://planetmath.org/proofofbarbalatslemma
Does anyone have an citeable reference that has this simple extension? Like anywhere that might have used this extension works too.
Edit: this question actually states what I am looking for:
Can I apply Barbalat's lemma when the derivative of a function approaches a uniformly continuous function?
I just need it to be from a citeable source.
To better explain, Barbalat's lemma says that if $f(t)$ approaches a limit as $t$ approaches infinity, and if it's derivative $\dot{f}(t)$ is uniformly continuous, then $\dot{f}$ must approach 0. In the first linked proof, $y(t)=\dot{f}(t)$

Can you fully state Barbalats lemma? I also don't know what you mean by derivative since the link mentions no derivatives

Barbalat's lemma says that if $f(t)$ approaches a limit as $t$ approaches infinity, and if it's derivative $\dot{f}(t)$ is uniformly continuous, then $\dot{f}$ must approach 0. In the linked proof, $y(t)$ should be the derivative $\dot{f}$, and its integral is $f(t)$.

if you have the proof already, and you have to cite something, what's stopping you from citing from MSE? some things in math do not require citations (if they are perturbations of well known things), and there's no issue about a source being "authoritative" or not because everyone can just read the proof and see that it's true.

Unfortunately my advisor wants one from like a textbook. Its for a paper and we are not in mathematics.
